# Is it possible to route audio via different software?

Tags: audio

I use my rpi3 for a bunch of things, probably too many things. At the moment I use it for kodi, which plays audio through the HDMI output, and it's great. I would like to add some mopidy audio support, however I would like to use the audio jack. Is it possible to route audio through different outputs for different software on the rpi3? I have searched and I think my google fu is failing me as I can't find the right answer

Comment: I do not know mopidy, but for the Analog output (AKA JACK or TTRS) in place of HDMI audio output you can just 'right click' on the Volume icon of raspbian desktop and select Analog. A command line must exist for do the same thing on raspbian ligth I suppose.If this can bring you a little help.

Comment: You can check here for command line : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=203756   , `Auto:
amixer cset numid=3 0
,3.5mm Jack: amixer cset numid=3 1
,HDMI:
amixer cset numid=3 2`

Comment: But maybe you want for example that Kodi uses the output audio HDMI and Mopidy audio output JACK? If so, I do not know a way...

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm after, a more programmatic way to do the audio routing automatically. Thanks tho